# Delete a data of my database from AS3

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to delete a data from my database with ActionScript 3.

I've created a php on my server :

```
<?php
include ("shared/connect.php");
$idToDelete   = $_POST['idToDelete'];

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"
DELETE  FROM `annoncesNew` WHERE id=$idToDelete");
?>
```

Then I have to send the variable `idToDelete` to this php in order to delete the entry.

So I did :

deleteBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, deleteThisAnnonce);

```
function deleteThisAnnonce(event:MouseEvent):void { 
    trace("deleteThisAnnonce");
var variablesDelete:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
var varDelete:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.***com/***/deleteAnnonce.php");
varDelete.method=URLRequestMethod.POST;
varDelete.data=variablesDelete;

var varLoaderDelete:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
varLoaderDelete.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
varLoaderDelete.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completeHandlerDelete);
ValidateAndSendDelete();
function completeHandlerDelete(event:Event):void{
            trace("Data Sent");

}
function ValidateAndSendDelete():void{
        trace("deleting"+item.id);  //item.id is my the ID. When I trace the output is 144 so it's good.    
        variablesDelete.idToDelete = item.id;
        varLoaderDelete.load(varDelete);
    }
}
```

So, with this code, it's supposed to delete the data where id = 144. But I've got this error when click on the `deleteBtn` :  `Error: Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs..`

(all the traces are working correctly but my data isn't delete).

I've tried my php by changing `DELETE  FROM`annoncesNew WHERE id=$idToDelete");`with`DELETE  FROM `annoncesNew WHERE id=144");` and execute it on my webbrowser and it worked (the line with the id 144 was deleted).

Weirdly, **the line is delete with my AS3 code** (so the code is working) but it throws this error 2101 anyway. Any idea why ?

Thx

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that I changed it. The code is working (the line is delete by the AS3 code but it throws an error anyway. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is not in your AS3 code but that your PHP script is not returning any values back to Flash. Try to add this to your PHP script:

```
echo "Status=true";
```

And you might need this in your AS3:

```
varLoaderDelete.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
```

Comment: it was `varLoaderDelete.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;`